# Extra Value is being added to the sum (total) eg : 50,173+50,173 = 153219?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sum, double

> I have a string arraylist with numbers like ["51,073","51,074","51,073"] now i want to convert this into a Double ArrayList and calculate the sum of the numbers in the array list.

```
 private ArrayList<String> totals = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Double> demototal = new ArrayList<>();
String total = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_TOTAL);
totals.add(total);

/*converting all values from totals array to Double and add to arraylist demototal*/
 for (int i = 0; i < totals.size(); i++) {
            final String value = totals.get(i);
            double total_ary = (double)Math.round((Double.parseDouble(value))*100.0)/100.0;
            demototal.add(total_ary);
        }

String amount = Double.toString(setArrayListElement(demototal));
        textViewSum.setText(amount);//set total text to amount


//calculate amount here we pass setArrayListElement as Double arraylist
    private Double setArrayListElement(ArrayList inArray) {
        Double amount = 0.0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++) {
            amount +=  Double.valueOf(Math.round((Double) inArray.get(i))*100.0)/100.0;
        }
        return amount;
    }
```

> For more clarity I am adding some more code.Please help!

```
private void showItem(String json) {
    String itembarcode = "";
    String itemdesc = "";
    String weight = "";
    String rate = "";
    String making = "";
    String netrate = "";
    String total = "";


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ParseBarcode.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject itemData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        itembarcode = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_BARCODE);
        itemdesc = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_DESC);
        weight = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_WEIGHT);
        rate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_RATE);
        making = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_MAKING);
        netrate = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_NETRATE);
        total = itemData.getString(ParseBarcode.KEY_TOTAL);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //table started

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rowParams.setMargins(16, 0, 16, 0);

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(AddInvEst.this);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow(AddInvEst.this);
    newRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

    barCode = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    barCode.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    barCode.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    itemDesc = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemDesc.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemDesc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    weightLine = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    weightLine.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.75f));
    weightLine.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    rateAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);
    rateAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    rateAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    rateAmount.addTextChangedListener(rateTextWatcher);

    makingAmount = new EditText(AddInvEst.this);
    makingAmount.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    makingAmount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    makingAmount.addTextChangedListener(mkAmountTextWatcher);

    netRate = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    netRate.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
    netRate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    netrates.add(netrate);

    itemtotal = new TextView(AddInvEst.this);
    itemtotal.setLayoutParams(rowParams);
    itemtotal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    totals.add(total);

    //converting all values from totals array to Double and add to arraylist demototal
    for (int i = 0; i < totals.size(); i++) {
        final String value = totals.get(i);
        double total_ary = (double)Math.round((Double.parseDouble(value))*100.0)/100.0;
        demototal.add(total_ary);
    }

    barCode.setText(itembarcode);
    itemDesc.setText(itemdesc);
    weightLine.setText(weight);
    rateAmount.setText(rate);
    makingAmount.setText(making);
    netRate.setText(netrate);
    itemtotal.setText(total);
    String amount = Double.toString(setArrayListElement(demototal));
    textViewSum.setText(amount);//set total text to amount
    //textViewVat.setText(vatAmt);

    newRow.addView(barCode);
    newRow.addView(itemDesc);
    newRow.addView(weightLine);
    newRow.addView(rateAmount);
    newRow.addView(makingAmount);
    newRow.addView(netRate);
    newRow.addView(itemtotal);
    itemTable.addView(newRow);

}

//calculate amount here we pass setArrayListElement as Double arraylist
private Double setArrayListElement(ArrayList inArray) {
    Double amount = 0.0d;
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.size(); i++) {
        amount +=  Double.valueOf(Math.round((Double) inArray.get(i))*100.0)/100.0;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your code could be a lot cleaner by using `foreach` loops, which may also make it easier for you to spot the error.

Comment: Try printing out the scanned double array using Arrays.toString() and see if it contains what you expect.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the sum total.The first time i add a product the sum or total is 0.0 and the 2nd time i add a item the sum total becomes the sum of the two items added.But when the third item is added i actually get the total of 5 items.

Comment: @TimB tried Using a toast like Toast.makeText(AddInvEst.this, total_ary+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and on my 2nd attempt the toast appears twice i.e two values got added the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

You add elements to `demototal` but never remove them or wipe the list. That means it will just keep growing for ever.

Comment: can you give me a example as to how can do that? Thanks

Comment: on the first attempt one item is getting added on the 2nd attempt 2 items are getting added on the 3rd attempt 3 items are getting added.

Comment: So think about why that might happen. Try doing what I said in a comment or stepping through in a debugger...